# Mongo $in query works in mongo but not in sails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

Basically the query works in mongo but not in sails controller:

```
    db.membermodel.find({identifier:{$in:["2","3","4"]}); // works

    MemberModel.find({
        identifier:{$in:["2","3","4"]},
    }).then(function(members){
        // doesn't work
    });
```

data returned:

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("52d1a484f2b5e88cb5d4072c"), "identifier" : "2", "deviceToken" : "token2"}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("52d1a487f2b5e88cb5d4072d"), "identifier" : "3", "deviceToken" : "token3"}
```

Thanks,
Mars

Comment: What kind of data matches in the shell? Can you post exactly the result in case it's small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the way to do `in` queries with Waterline.  You simply set the attribute you're selecting to the array value:

```
MemberModel.find({
    identifier:["2","3","4"]
}).exec(function(err, members){
    ...
});
```

If you really need to use low-level Mongo features, you can get an instance of the native collection with

```
MemberModel.native(function(err, collection) {
   //do native mongo driver stuff with collection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand how the model is being queried but I suggest you to "spy" what's Mongo getting as the MVC framework query, due to this is not a direct query to Mongo, it's passed through the framework.
I'm quite sure you're still developing so you have access to your mongo instance, restart it using full profile (the trick is everything is slow under 1ms)

mongod --profile=1 --slowms=1 &

Tail the resulting log which normally is in

/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

with the command

tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

Send your query again and check what MongoDb is executing.